# JavaScript strict type checking fails

Tags: javascript

I was checking three Strings equality;

```
var str1 = "Hello World!";
var str2 = "Hello \
    World!";
var str3 = "Hello" + " World!";
//console.log(str1===str2);//true
// console.log(str2===str3);//true
console.log(str1 === str2 === str3); //false
```

How can we check this scenario where I want to compare 3 variables?

Comment: `str1 === str2 === str3` ==> `str1 === str2` ==> `true` ==> `true === str3` ==> `false`.

Comment: In this specific example, it's `false === str3`

Comment: It's doesn't make me `true` when compare `str1` and `str2` also .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't totally clear to me.

### Assuming your question is about how to compare the equality of 3 strings:

With

```
console.log(str1 === str2 === str3);
```

you're checking

```
(str1 === str2) === str3
```

(yes, the associativity is [left to right](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) here)

That is, you're comparing a boolean to a string.

What you want is

```
(str1 === str2) && (str2 === str3)
```

### Assuming your question is about how to compare strings but not caring about the numbers and types of spaces (see note below):

Then the best would be to normalize your strings using a function like

```
function normalize(str){
    return str.replace(/\s+/g,' ');
}
```

And you can define a function comparing all your strings:

```
function allEquals(strs) {
   var p;
   for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
       if (typeof arguments[i] !== "string") return false;
       var s = arguments[i].replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
       if (p !== undefined && s!==p) return false;
       p = s;
   }
   return true;
}

console.log(allEquals(str1, str2, str3));
```

**Note:** multi-line string literals are painful. Those strings are different:

```
var str2 = "Hello \
    World!";
var str4 = "Hello \
World!";
```

Comment: I also thought same, but the strings are not equal.

Comment: Ok, but mention that `var str2 = "Hello \
    World!";` string contains few spaces(_indented_) so this is not same as others.

Comment: I don't really get the downvotes there. Please ask in a comment when something isn't clear.

Comment: @Tushar str2 is also same you can see the JSBIN here http://jsbin.com/tolamihogi/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @Tushar It's the same in the bin because there's no indentation. The spaces in your question come from the indentation (that's a reason why developers avoir multi-line string literals)